# How to append the list of dictionary to same list in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm having a JSON with nested values. I need to remove the key of the nested field and need to keep the values as plain JSON.

**JSON**(Structure of my JSON)

```
[
  {
"id":"101",
"name":"User1",
"place":{ 
    "city":"City1",
    "district":"District1",
    "state":"State1",
    "country":"Country1" 
    },
"access":[{"status":"available"}]
  }
]
```

I need to get the JSON output as:

**Expected Output:**

```
[
 {
 "id":"101",
 "name":"User1",
 "city":"City1",
 "district":"District1",
 "state":"State1",
 "country":"Country1" 
 "access":[{"status":"available"}]
 }
]
```

What i need is:

1. I need to parse the JSON
2. Get the  `Place`field out of the JSON
3. Remove the key and brackets and append the values to existing

**Python**

```
for i in range(0,len(json_data)):
   place_data = json_data[i]['place']
   print(type(place_data)) #dict
   del place_data['place']
```

Any approach to get the expected output in python.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this could be by

```
for i in json_data:
    i.update(i.pop("place"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this with multiple "keys" updated...
This would only work for a single nested level as described in the original question

```
def expand(array):
    flatten = list()
    for obj in array:
        temp = {}
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                temp.update(value)
            else:
                temp.update({key:value})
        flatten.append(temp)    
    return flatten
```